# My script runs on the head node but fails when I use Slurm to send to another node

Tags: slurm

I have some python code on a remote machine. When I run the code on the head node, it runs perfectly. When I use `slurm` the job begins, but after a few minutes it seems to stall (from looking at the output) and then after a while the job seems to die and disappear from the `squeue` without any error message. The command I run is:

```
sbatch --wrap="python my_code.py" -J run1 -N 1 --cpus-per-task=8 -o run1.o
```

I know it's difficult to say what's happening without knowing the details of the code, but I'm wondering what could cause a code to run on the head node of a remote machine, but stall (after partially running) when using `sbatch` to send the job (same code) to a node?

Comment: One possible reason might be the usage of  `wget` or `curl`. The compute node is not connected to the internet.

Comment: The content of `run1.o` should provide insights

Comment: @PrakharSharma unfortunately, I have no such links, so it's not that. Good idea though.

Comment: @damienfrancois the output file just had the expected outputs but then stops. There are no error messages, which is why it's difficult to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Are you using some library which has a `verbose` attribute? May be the `verbose` is hiding the error in the output file.

Comment: Hmm not that I know of.

Comment: please paste your code.